# How to set Authorization token with axios in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I want to use axios in api test. To initialize client I need first to set auth token, which I expect to get with axios as well.How to get it form async code?

```
const a = require('axios');

  getToken = () => {
    var axios =a.create({
        baseURL: 'http://local.v2.app.com/api/auth/v1.0',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      });

      return axios.post('/credentials/login', {
        username: '1@test.com',
        password: 'Test@1234'
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data.data.token;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }

  const client=a.create({
    baseURL: 'http://local.v2.app.com/api/auth/v1.0',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':  getToken()
},
  });

  module.exports = client;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, getToken should be async (or just return promise):

```
async getToken() {
    var axios = a.create({
        baseURL: 'http://local.v2.app.com/api/auth/v1.0',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/credentials/login', {
        username: '1@test.com',
        password: 'Test@1234'
      })
      return response.data.data.token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Then you can mock `request`:

```
const client = a.create({
  baseURL: 'http://local.v2.app.com/api/auth/v1.0',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
const request = client.request

const addToken = (token) => (data, headers) => {
  headers.Authorization = token
  return data
}

client.request = (config = {}) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  token = await getToken()
  if (!config.transformRequest) config.transformRequest = []
  config.transformRequest.push(addToken(token))
  request(config).then(resolve, reject)
})

module.exports = client
```

Yes, bit messy, feel free to refactor!

axios has `request` function which makes requests, others like get, post are aliases. This code patches request to get token first and then continue request.

transformRequest is took from axious readme on github, there is a comment "You may modify the headers object" so it is legal.

P.S good question, don't know why -1

Comment: Do I understand right, since client.request is promise, I can't use this client immediately, because token might not been loaded? And need use it in sync or though .then, sounds really inconvenient.

Comment: Hey, are you going to use .request or .get or .post not like a promise?
In my assumption my answer should not change usual way of further using axios.

Comment: I expect to use it like this `const client = require('./client');

client.get('/demo/search')
`

Comment: And how you are going to get response?

Comment: guess I will need to use it in sync await